# How do I return the body in the mail? MailApp.sendEmail() error

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script

```
emailAddress1=row[0];
emailAddress2=row[1];
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1 + "," + emailAddress2 ,subject,{'htmlBody':message},{noReply:true});
```

This sends a mail from noreply but in the body says [object][object].
How do i return the body in the mail

Comment: What format do you want your body in?

Comment: Hey guys thanks. I got it. This will be: MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1 + "," + emailAddress2 ,subject,' ',{'htmlBody':message,noReply:true}); //Returns the body in the mail. Was using the options argument incorrectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browsers native JSON.stringify method. Works with nested objects and all major browsers support this method.

```
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```